# Datajs OData.read function not firing through PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, odata, datajs

I'm trying to package up a mobile web application into an iOS app using PhoneGap and JQuery Mobile.  The application uses Datajs to make OData requests to another site.  I've set External Hosts to '*' in Cordova.plist, and the requests work fine when using the same files through a web browser.

The problem is that as soon as it's packaged into an iOS app the OData.read() functions are completely skipped over like they aren't even there.  Here's the code that's causing the problem:

```
var myURI = baseURL + "GetIndustries";
    console.log("before request");
    OData.read({requestUri: myURI, username: username, password: password}, function (data){
                          console.log("successful request");
               for (var i=0; i<data.results.length; i++) {
            industries[i]=data.results[i];
        }
        }, function(err){
            console.log("error: "+err);
    });
    console.log("after request...");
```

When running the application, the log outputs are:

```
2012-12-21 11:05:48.104 opportunities[298:907] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2012-12-21 11:06:04.791 opportunities[298:907] [LOG] before request
2012-12-21 11:06:04.806 opportunities[298:907] [LOG] after request...
```

To me that indicates that it's completely skipping the OData function altogether, even the error handling.  I'm using datajs-1.1.0 and version 1.2.0 of JQueryMobile.

Any help or pointers would be massively appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> To me that indicates that it's completely skipping the OData function altogether

Wrong. The AJAX request to `requestUri` is sent asynchronously by datajs. The OData function you refer to is a **callback** function, which means it will be called later on -- ie: when the server has composed a reply and datajs has received that reply.

As to why your callback function never gets called: please check your parameters when calling `OData.read`. The [snippets](http://datajs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=OData%20Code%20Snippets&referringTitle=Documentation) provide some examples. Also see the [detailed documentation for OData.read](http://datajs.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=datajs%20OData%20API&referringTitle=Documentation#OData.read).